# Why Kube-proxy not working ? No DNS resolution

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

i've juste set up a fresh cluster with kubeadm and kubernetes 1.21. All pods are mark ready. But i can't access any of them. After digging into the problem, it appear that no DNS resolution is possible. It seems that kube-proxy does not work.

this is a log of a kube-proxy pods

```
I0712 05:50:46.511967       1 node.go:172] Successfully retrieved node IP: x.x.x.x
I0712 05:50:46.512039       1 server_others.go:140] Detected node IP x.x.x.x
W0712 05:50:46.512077       1 server_others.go:598] Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy
I0712 05:50:46.545626       1 server_others.go:206] kube-proxy running in dual-stack mode, IPv4-primary
I0712 05:50:46.545672       1 server_others.go:212] Using iptables Proxier.
I0712 05:50:46.545692       1 server_others.go:219] creating dualStackProxier for iptables.
W0712 05:50:46.545715       1 server_others.go:512] detect-local-mode set to ClusterCIDR, but no IPv6 cluster CIDR defined, , defaulting to no-op detect-local for IPv6
I0712 05:50:46.546089       1 server.go:643] Version: v1.21.2
I0712 05:50:46.549861       1 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 196608
I0712 05:50:46.550300       1 config.go:224] Starting endpoint slice config controller
I0712 05:50:46.550338       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoint slice config
I0712 05:50:46.550332       1 config.go:315] Starting service config controller
I0712 05:50:46.550354       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
W0712 05:50:46.553020       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
W0712 05:50:46.555115       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
I0712 05:50:46.650614       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for service config 
I0712 05:50:46.650634       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for endpoint slice config 
W0712 05:57:14.556916       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
W0712 06:06:34.558550       1 warnings.go:70] discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1 EndpointSlice is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+; use discovery.k8s.io/v1 EndpointSlice
```

and this is my pods running :

```
kube-system     pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-qpf5m                  1/1     Running   1          8h
kube-system     pod/coredns-558bd4d5db-r5jwz                  1/1     Running   0          8h
kube-system     pod/etcd-master2                              1/1     Running   3          20h
kube-system     pod/kube-apiserver-master2                    1/1     Running   3          20h
kube-system     pod/kube-controller-manager-master2           1/1     Running   3          8h
kube-system     pod/kube-flannel-ds-b7xrm                     1/1     Running   0          8h
kube-system     pod/kube-flannel-ds-hcn7f                     1/1     Running   0          8h
kube-system     pod/kube-flannel-ds-rx8j6                     1/1     Running   1          8h
kube-system     pod/kube-flannel-ds-wc2jc                     1/1     Running   0          8h
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-48wmr                          1/1     Running   0          25m
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-4gw8t                          1/1     Running   0          25m
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-h9djp                          1/1     Running   0          25m
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-r4k9t                          1/1     Running   0          24m
kube-system     pod/kube-scheduler-master2                    1/1     Running   3          20h
```

the command `kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox nslookup kubernetes.default` give me :

```
Address 1: x.x.x.x

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
pod "busybox" deleted
pod default/busybox terminated (Error)
```

My iptables rules :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-NODEPORTS  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes health check service ports */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  10.244.0.0/16        anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.244.0.0/16       

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
DROP       all  -- !127.0.0.0/8          127.0.0.0/8          /* block incoming localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-NODEPORTS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-PROXY-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

any idea?

[Edit]

```
#kubectl edit cm -n kube-system kubelet-config-1.21
apiVersion: v1
data:
  kubelet: |
    apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
    authentication:
      anonymous:
        enabled: false
      webhook:
        cacheTTL: 0s
        enabled: true
      x509:
        clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    authorization:
      mode: Webhook
      webhook:
        cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
        cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
    cgroupDriver: systemd
    clusterDNS:
    - 10.96.0.10
    clusterDomain: cluster.local
```

```
#kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   22h
```

Answer (score 0):

Kube-proxy it's network service.
DNS-provider responsible for DNS resolution. As I see, you already have coredns installed.
Check your kubelet configuration. It should point to correct service, and this service should be accessible within your pods.
Also please check if your `firewalld` or `iptables` service is disabled on all nodes.

Like this:

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: "/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem"
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
clusterDomain: "cluster.local"
clusterDNS:
  - "10.33.0.10"
```

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.33.0.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   35h
```

And then:

```
kubectl exec -ti net-diag-86589fd8f5-r28qq -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.33.0.10
Address:        10.33.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.33.0.1
```

UPD.

I Just noticed that you have Docker as a container runtime and flannel as a network provider. Per my understanding the problem may be is that Docker messing around with your iptables rules, try to set all docker rules as prmissive and see if it'll work.

I'm not a big expert in iptables configuration but something like this may help:

```
https://unrouted.io/2017/08/15/docker-firewall/
```

Also if you are using Flannel, make sure that you are using correct `iface` option. It may be critical if you are running non-cloud installations.

```
https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/configuration.md#key-command-line-options
```

Comment: I say kube-proxy does not working because of kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-kube-proxy-working. 

What is the net-diag pods?

Comment: kube-proxy it's just name of the service which pointing to my Coredns application.
net-diag it's: praqma/network-multitool

Comment: I edit my question . As you can see, the IP used is correct

Comment: Can you actually access 10.96.0.10:53 from your pods or it's timing out?
Another question is: do you have firewalld disabled?

Comment: net diag availabe here: https://github.com/Praqma/Network-MultiTool/tree/master/kubernetes

Comment: `sudo systemctl status firewalld.service  Unit firewalld.service could not be found.`
                  `kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox telnet 10.96.0.10 53` => `telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.96.0.10): Connection timed out
`